# High-DPI with Ubuntu 16.04 on Hyper-V

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, virtualization, hyper-v, high-dpi

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on a Hyper-V virtual machine hosted on Windows 10. It all runs on computer with a 4k UHD display, so the high dpi scaling (200%) is enabled on Windows.

My problem is by default the Ubuntu instance has a low display resolution and is scaled up. This is a good solution if the guest operating system has no high dpi support or the computing power is low. But the disadvantage is that the picture is not sharp, because it is scaled up.

Is it possible to change this so that one pixel in Ubuntu equals to one physical pixel on the 4k display. Then the Ubuntu Instance can set a higher resolution and use its own high DPI scaling. In that case anything should be sharp and in good quality.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to set the scaling to 100% from the View menu of the "Virtual Machine Connection" window. You can then increase the resolution by following [these instructions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/virtual_pc_guy/2014/09/19/changing-ubuntu-screen-resolution-in-a-hyper-v-vm/). You are unlikely to be happy with the result (well, I wasn't happy with the result), however, since there is a [8M framebuffer limitation](https://github.com/LIS/lis-next/issues/318), meaning you can't bump the resolution much above 1920x1080.

My current solution is to run [VcXsrv](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vcxsrv/) as an X server under Windows, and to SSH into the VM using [PuTTY](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/); you can then open X clients and change their size as you like.